# How to format horizontal rules?

Tags: asp.net, rule

I want to have many horizontal rules with the same formating.
I'm trying with CssClass and got an error:

```
<hr CssClass="hRules"/>  // error: Attribute 'CssClass' is not a valid attribute of element 'hr'.
```

What is the solution, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not simply use the class attribute?

```
<hr class="hRules" />
```

And in Css somewhere:

```
.hRules{
   height:1px;
   color:#C7C7C7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For normal HTML controls, you must use the `class` attribute. The `CssClass` attribute is used for asp controls. You could probably still use the `CssClass`attribute for your `hr`control, but you would probably have to set it a `runat="server"`too

Comment: Then you'll have to use the `class`attribute.